# How to set duration of task based on index on machine ortools?

Tags: python, schedule, or-tools

I have the following code to create a schedule. I would like to set: duration = max_duration if task is the first on machine or the previous task on the same machine has different id or there is an idle time on the same machine before current task. In all other cases, I would like to set duration = min_duration.

I have no clue how to check these conditions in ortools.

```
def flexible_jobshop():
    
    """Solve a small flexible jobshop problem."""
    # Data part.
    
    # For us:
        # job is set of 2 robots, it consists of two tasks: robot for filling the queue and robot for processing it
        # each of them has multiple alternatives for each of the machines it can be run on

    jobs = [  # task = (id, time per single item, priorita, machine id options, start time min, start time max) 
        [  # Job 0
            ["gga5", 3, 1, ["a", "c"], 10],  #task0
            ["gga6", 2, 2, ["b", "c"]],    #task1
            ["gga6", 2, 2, ["b", "c"]],
            ["gga6", 2, 2, ["b", "c"]],
            ["gga6", 2, 2, ["b", "c"]],
            ["gga6", 2, 2, ["b", "c"]],
            ["gga6", 2, 2, ["b", "c"]],
            ["gga6", 2, 2, ["b", "c"]],
            ["gga6", 2, 2, ["b", "c"]]
         
        ],
        [  # Job 1
            ["h4jk", 4, 1, ["a", "b", "c"], 8, 12], 
            ["h4jl", 1, 1, ["a"]], 
            ["h4jl", 1, 1, ["a"]], 
            ["h4jl", 1, 1, ["a"]], 
            ["h4jl", 1, 1, ["a"]], 
            ["h4jl", 1, 1, ["a"]], 
            ["h4jl", 1, 1, ["a"]], 
            ["h4jl", 1, 1, ["a"]], 
            ["h4jl", 1, 1, ["a"]]
            
        ],
        [  # Job 2
            ["p0o1", 2, 1, ["a", "b"], 0, 10], 
            ["p0o2", 3, -1, ["a", "b", "c"]],
            ["p0o2", 3, -1, ["a", "b", "c"]],
            ["p0o2", 3, -1, ["a", "b", "c"]],
            ["p0o2", 3, -1, ["a", "b", "c"]],
            ["p0o2", 3, -1, ["a", "b", "c"]],
            ["p0o2", 3, -1, ["a", "b", "c"]],
            ["p0o2", 3, -1, ["a", "b", "c"]],
            ["p0o2", 3, -1, ["a", "b", "c"]],
            ["p0o2", 3, -1, ["a", "b", "c"]]  
        ]
    ]

    ID_ROBOT = 0
    PROCESSING_TIME = 1
    PRIORITA = 2
    MACHINE_ID = 3
    START_TIME_MIN = 4
    START_TIME_MAX = 5
    
    TIME_PENALTY = 1
    
    num_jobs = len(jobs)
    all_jobs = range(num_jobs)

    list_machines = set([alt for job in jobs for task in job for alt in task[MACHINE_ID]])
    num_machines = len(list_machines) # 1 position of machine id
    all_machines = range(num_machines)

    # Model the flexible jobshop problem.
    model = cp_model.CpModel()

    horizon = 0
    for job in jobs:
        for task in job:
            max_task_duration = task[PROCESSING_TIME] + TIME_PENALTY
            horizon += max_task_duration 
            
    print('Horizon = %i' % horizon)

    # Global storage of variables.
    intervals_per_resources = collections.defaultdict(list)
    durations_per_resources = collections.defaultdict(list)
    starts = {}  # indexed by (job_id, task_id).
    presences = {}  # indexed by (job_id, task_id, alt_id).
    job_ends = []


    # Scan the jobs and create the relevant variables and intervals.
    for job_id in all_jobs:
        job = jobs[job_id] 
        num_tasks = len(job)
        previous_end = None
        for task_id in range(num_tasks): 
            task = job[task_id]  
            
            min_duration = task[PROCESSING_TIME]
            max_duration = min_duration + TIME_PENALTY

            num_alternatives = len(task[MACHINE_ID])
            all_alternatives = range(num_alternatives)

            # Create main interval for the task.
            suffix_name = '_j%i_t%i' % (job_id, task_id)
            start = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, 'start' + suffix_name) 
                 #start of this given task could be somewhere between 0 and end = horizon = total duration?
                # if we want to run the schedule between 8 and 15, should we specify it here?
            duration = model.NewIntVar(min_duration, max_duration,
                                       'duration' + suffix_name)
            end = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, 'end' + suffix_name)
            interval = model.NewIntervalVar(start, duration, end,
                                            'interval' + suffix_name)

          #  model.Add(duration == duration + 1)
            # Store the start for the solution.
            starts[(job_id, task_id)] = start       
            
            # Add penalty for switching between processes
            
            
                
            # Add precedence with previous task in the same job.
                # filler runs before processor!
                # so if each job is in our case two robots: one filler of the queue and the 2nd the processor
                # then their precedence is secured
            if previous_end is not None:
                model.Add(start >= previous_end)
            previous_end = end

            
            # If there is time restrictions for each day, then implement
            try: 
                start_limit = task[START_TIME_MIN]         
                model.Add(starts[(job_id, task_id)] >= start_limit)
            except:
                  print(f"For {task[ID_ROBOT]} there is no limit for start time")
            
            try:
                end_limit = task[START_TIME_MAX]
                model.Add(starts[(job_id, task_id)] <= start_limit)
            except:
                  print(f"For {task[ID_ROBOT]} there is no limit for end time")
            
            # Create alternative intervals: choose only one of alternatives - single job runs on single machine
            if num_alternatives > 1:
                l_presences = []
                for alt_id in all_alternatives:
                    alt_suffix = '_j%i_t%i_a%i' % (job_id, task_id, alt_id)
                    l_presence = model.NewBoolVar('presence' + alt_suffix)
                    l_start = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, 'start' + alt_suffix)
                    l_duration = model.NewIntVar(min_duration, max_duration,
                                       'duration' + suffix_name)
                    l_end = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, 'end' + alt_suffix)
                    l_interval = model.NewOptionalIntervalVar(
                        l_start, l_duration, l_end, l_presence,
                        'interval' + alt_suffix)
                    l_presences.append(l_presence)

                    # Link the primary/global variables with the local ones.
                    model.Add(start == l_start).OnlyEnforceIf(l_presence)
                    model.Add(duration == l_duration).OnlyEnforceIf(l_presence)
                    model.Add(end == l_end).OnlyEnforceIf(l_presence)

                    # Add the local interval to the right machine.
                    intervals_per_resources[task[MACHINE_ID][alt_id]].append(l_interval)

                    # Store the presences for the solution.
                    presences[(job_id, task_id, alt_id)] = l_presence

                    
                # Select exactly one presence variable.
                model.AddExactlyOne(l_presences)
            else:
                intervals_per_resources[task[MACHINE_ID][0]].append(interval)
                presences[(job_id, task_id, 0)] = model.NewConstant(1)

        job_ends.append(previous_end)
        

    # Create machines constraints: No everlap of jobs per singe interval
    for machine_id in list_machines:
        intervals = intervals_per_resources[machine_id]
        if len(intervals) > 1:
            #print(f"For machine {machine_id} there is more than 1 interval.")
            model.AddNoOverlap(intervals)

    # Makespan objective
    makespan = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, 'makespan')
    model.AddMaxEquality(makespan, job_ends)
    model.Minimize(makespan)

    # Solve model.
    solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
    solution_printer = SolutionPrinter()
    status = solver.Solve(model, solution_printer)

    print(solver.StatusName(status))
    # Print final solution.
    for job_id in all_jobs:
        print('Job %i:' % job_id)
        for task_id in range(len(jobs[job_id])):
            print(starts[(job_id, task_id)])
            start_value = solver.Value(starts[(job_id, task_id)])
            machine = -1
            duration = -1
            selected = -1
            for alt_id in range(len(jobs[job_id][task_id][MACHINE_ID])):
                if solver.Value(presences[(job_id, task_id, alt_id)]):
                    robot = jobs[job_id][task_id][ID_ROBOT]
                    duration = jobs[job_id][task_id][PROCESSING_TIME]
                    machine = jobs[job_id][task_id][MACHINE_ID][alt_id]
                    selected = alt_id
            print(
                '  task_%i_%i (id: %s) starts at %i (alt %i, machine %s, min duration %i)' %
                (job_id, task_id, robot, start_value, selected, machine, duration))

    print('Solve status: %s' % solver.StatusName(status))
    print('Optimal objective value: %i' % solver.ObjectiveValue())
    print('Statistics')
    print('  - conflicts : %i' % solver.NumConflicts())
    print('  - branches  : %i' % solver.NumBranches())
    print('  - wall time : %f s' % solver.WallTime())

    
flexible_jobshop()
```

I tried to do the following but it is wrong because it makes the decision based on how the tasks are organised in the input data not in the machine. On the top of that the condition

```
previous_end == start
```

does not even work. I dont understand why.

```
            equal = model.NewBoolVar("equal")
            print(previous_end == start)
            if previous_end == start:
                model.Add(equal == 1)
            else:
                model.Add(equal == 0)
            
            try:
                if previous_robot == task[ID_ROBOT]: # jsou po sobě v datech ne na machine! Špatně!
                    model.Add(duration == min_duration).OnlyEnforceIf(equal)
                else:
                    model.Add(duration == max_duration)
            except:
                model.Add(duration == max_duration)
            
       
            previous_robot = task[ID_ROBOT]
```

I also checked circuit constraint but I dont understand it from the sample codes I saw online.

Can somebody please help? Sample code how to solve the issue would be very much appreciated!

Thank you!!

Comment: really look at some scheduling with transition/setup examples. The code is well documented https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/82750ac12f1ee5354e1c7869894d9af3508778f2/examples/python/single_machine_scheduling_with_setup_release_due_dates_sat.py#L209

Comment: Discussion is happening here: https://groups.google.com/g/or-tools-discuss/c/PGVc-FjC_c8